# Excel, how to find column number of min value?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a table in Excel.

Can anyone help me find the column number of the cell where the min value of the row is?

Example: 200 is the min value in row1 and has the column number 1.
Is there a function that returns the column number of the min value?

```
       col1  col2  col3  col4  col5 

row1 - 200 - 300 - 400 - 500 - 600

row2 - ... - ... - ... - ... - ...
```

Comment: Check out http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=89269 -- it's for a similar problem, but with rows instead of columns. I expect you can probably edit it to match your needs.

Comment: just for clarification - do you really need the number of the column, or is it sufficient to highlight the cell with the lowest value?

Comment: Do you need the lowest column number for a range of rows combined? if not, then @kopischke offered, per row what works

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming your data is in columns A to D, the following formula in E will return the relative numeric index of the smallest value (with 1 = 1st column = A, 2 = 2nd column = B, etc.) for row 1:

```
=MATCH(MIN(A1:D1),A1:D1,0)
```

Explanation: the `MATCH()` function returns a relative index for a cell value in a cell range, and the nested `MIN()` for the same range provides the value to check for.

Comment: +1 this works if checking each row separately. It wasn't clear to me whether a range is being looked at for the column with a min value however.

Comment: nice one (and +1). I've submitted an edit because the English version of Excel uses commas `,` instead of semi-colons `;` to separate arguments within a formula

Comment: @JMax: ugh, yeah, thanks for catching that – I translated the formula names but forgot about the semicolons.

Comment: Thanks! I used this with the index function...

INDEX($G$1:$IV$1;MATCH(MIN(G2:IV2);G2:IV2;0)) 
I have the column names in G1 to IV1 and this returns the column name where the min value is.

Comment: what if 2 columns have the same value, is it possible to shown both column names?

Comment: @SenthilAKumar This method only works if the `MIN(A1:D1)` is unique.  It's literally doing a lookup on the value returned by the `MIN` function.

Comment: I had done essentially this myself (min was already calculated in a different column) however I was getting some N/A results because of the third parameter to MATCH which I did not specify. The `0` here is essential.