# Find minimum value in a row and return corresponding column name

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

How do I find the minimum value in a row and return corresponding column name?

```
Month   Price 1   Price 2   Price 3
Jan     10,000    20,000    9,000
```

So in the end I wish the formula to return `Price 3` in a particular cell on a separate worksheet

Comment: Month Price 1 Price 2 Price 3
Jan 10,000 20,000 9,000

Comment: This is already discussed here in Super User. Please refer the link. http://superuser.com/questions/452154/excel-how-to-find-column-number-of-min-value

Answer (score 0):

As @vembutech already pointed out, you find the answer in [this SU comment](https://superuser.com/questions/452154/excel-how-to-find-column-number-of-min-value#comment527443_452166)

Adapted for your example

```
[F2]: =INDEX($B$1:$D$1,1,MATCH(MIN(B2:D2),B2:D2,0))
```

[image]